# Add Claim On Successful Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to add a claim to the user's identity after a successful user login. This is where I think it needs to happen:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, string myClaimValue)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View(model);
   }

   var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
   switch (result)
   {
      case SignInStatus.Success:
         UserManager.AddClaim(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new Claim("MyClaim", myClaimValue));
         return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
      case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
         return View("Lockout");
      case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
         return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
      case SignInStatus.Failure:
      default:
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
         return View(model);
   }
}
```

I think this is the right approach, but the call to `User.Identity.GetUserId()` throws an exception. It looks like `User.Identity` is not updated by the successful signin. In lieu of this reality, what is the best way for me to get the newly signed in user's id so that I can add a claim?

Or am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: @John Saunders Thanks! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think I'm doing it wrong. It seems to me that claims are things that identify a user. My goal in all of this is to store some data that is true about a user that is calculated on the client at login time. This data should not be stored in the database, but should be associated with the logged in user while he is logged in.

Comment: Claims do more than identify a user. They are a set of "propositions" that the user asserts are true. For instance, "I am in the following set of roles" is a reasonable claim.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for explaining. That makes sense and I think justifies the way I'm trying to use them.

Answer (score 5):

This will store claims to database    `UserManager.AddClaim(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new Claim("MyClaim", myClaimValue));`

If you want to associated claims with the logged-in user when he logs in,  You have to overwrite the `SignInAsync` method of `SignInManager`

```
public override async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser) { var userIdentity = await CreateUserIdentityAsync(user); // your code here userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Gender, "male")); // AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie); if (rememberBrowser) { var rememberBrowserIdentpublic override async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser)
{
    var userIdentity = await CreateUserIdentityAsync(user);

    // add your claims here
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Gender, "male"));
    //

    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);
    if (rememberBrowser)
    {
        var rememberBrowserIdentity = AuthenticationManager.CreateTwoFactorRememberBrowserIdentity(ConvertIdToString(user.Id));
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, userIdentity, rememberBrowserIdentity);
    }
    else
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, userIdentity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks. The problem is that when I try to access that claim in other controllers, it does not exist. Furthermore, when I create a new `ClaimIdentity` as you have done above, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false. I'm not sure if the problem is that the `User.Identity` doesn't seem to be completely initialized, or that I'm not doing anything with this new identity once I've created it.

Comment: @itslittlejohn this does not work as you said, updating answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll test this as soon as I can.

Comment: I ended up just using the session variable. This still doesn't work because my claim value is dynamically coming in from the sign in request. Because this seems so difficult to do with claims, I think it's the wrong approach. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 5):

Additional claims must be set before SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync is triggered. This can be done by a custom ClaimsIdentityFactory:

```
public class ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory : ClaimsIdentityFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    // This claim value is taken from Login View
    public static readonly string MyClaimKey = "app:MyClaimKey";
    public string MyClaimValue { get; set; }

    public async override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager, ApplicationUser user, string authenticationType)
    {
        var identity = await base.CreateAsync(manager, user, authenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(MyClaimKey, MyClaimValue));
        return identity;
    }
}
```

Apply this factory before sign in step:

```
UserManager.ClaimsIdentityFactory = new ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory() 
        { 
            MyClaimValue = loginModel.MyClaimValue
        };
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: Wasn't the question about how to add claims AFTER the successful login? Answering that claims "must be set before" login, without providing anything to support that statement is not really helpful to people reading the answer.

Comment: @MladenB. . You set up the claims factory to the signinmanager before signin, so that when the signin happens it uses the factory you prepared. You are right that this is related to the question but not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I did this and it worked:

1. fetch the user using UserName
2. check password using SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync()
3. add your custom Claims and Login using
   SignInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync()

Comment: That is available only in .NET Core but not in .NET Framework literally.