# How to get custom user property in Razor ASP.NET without any ViewModels?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I created my new custom property for User in ASP.NET project ("DarkTheme").
I have a problem (see below). I can access User.Identity.Name without any ViewModels. I can access User.Identity.IsInRole() and so on. But I cannot access my new property ("DarkTheme"). I do not want to use viewmodels (I would have to rewrite the whole application). Is there a way to go to the place where ASP.NET makes User.Identity.Name accessible without any ViewModels and add "DarkTheme" property?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah, looks like I missed something, deleted that post since it does not bring any value to question. you could try doing it through claims https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946453/add-claim-on-successful-login

Comment: Or you could use a ViewBag and put somewhere in the onActionExecuted method - ViewBag.DarkTheme = YourUser.DarkTheme. This way you are not linked to view model

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the answer to this problem, but I have a workaround.

I used User.IsInRole("DarkTheme") attribute to pass the value to the view (and load different css files depending on the value). It is the only role that user can assign to himself without manager permission.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OnActionExecuted` method in your controller in combination with dynamic `ViewBag`

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() || filterContext.IsChildAction) return; // you don't need styling for ajax requests which return json

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    YourUser user = ... // get user from db/claims or get theme from cookies etc.;
    ViewBag.DarkTheme = user.DarkTheme;
}
```

and in view it will be invoked simply by `@ViewBag.DarkTheme`, no namespace needed